# React Native Debugger

Tags: react-native, debugging, react-native-debugger

I am trying to debug my first React Native app. I have installed the React Native Debugger (not using chrome). However, every time I ty to debug my program and step over a method I get taken into runtime.js and other files I am not familiar with(JSTimer.js, MessageQueue.js RNDebuggerWorker.js to name a few). Any idea how to avoid this or what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: yeah, that's what happens with frameworks. Lots of calls to internal code happening in the background that you don't normally notice

Comment: Anything I can do to make debugging smoother?

Comment: Hi, how did you ended up solving this issue?